# Sort list in Python by letter mid way through string?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a program that saves a person's name and score in a .txt file like this:

```
Dave      : 5/10
Steven    : 3/10
Jo        : 10/10
```

So it basically adds spaces to the end of your name to make it exactly 10 characters long so all scores line up.

I have another program that sorts these scores alphabetically by the person's name, simply by using sort()

Is there a way I can sort them by score? In other words, use the sort() function but ignore the first 12 characters/only use the 13th character?

I don't want to completely strip off the name as I want the names to appear when the list is printed (in score order).

The only idea I had was to have a list that has the scores first and the names after, sorts them, then uses split to swap the names and scores around so in the final list it looks like the example above. This method seems tedius and like it might not work though.

Thanks!

Comment: `list.sort(key=lambda str: str[12:])`...!?

Comment: Oh this might work, I'll try it out, thanks!

Comment: @deceze: Well I don't think use `str` as a variable name is a good idea.

Comment: @Kevin Neither is `list`, this was mostly illustrative.

Comment: @deceze: Ah yeah. However I'd recommend `mylist.sort(key=lambda string: string[12:])`.

Comment: @deceze it will not work since you are making a string comparison on a int data

Answer (score 2):

> The only idea I had was to have a list that has the scores first and the names after, sorts them, then uses split to swap the names and scores around so in the final list it looks like the example above. This method seems tedius and like it might not work though.

Point 8 in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):

```
L.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split()[2].split('/')[0]))
```

Comment: @VigneshKalai: Right, my bad, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Represent your data as a list of tuples like that:

```
>>> l = [ ("Dave", 5), ("Steven", 3), ("Jo", 10) ]
```

You can do that:

```
>>> l = map(lambda x: (x[0],int(x[1])), re.findall("(\w+)[ \t]*:[ \t]*(\d+)\/\d+",txt))
('Dave', 5), ('Steven', 3), ('Jo', 10)]
```

Than to sort by names use:

```
>>> l.sort()
```

and to sort by scores use:

```
>>> l.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
```

To print, use:

```
for name, score in l:
    print name,"\t:",score,".",10
```

Comment: @Ambidextroid check updated answer: `l = map(lambda x: (x[0],int(x[1])), re.findall("(\w+)[ \t]*:[ \t]*(\d+)\/\d+",txt))`